Invoke `Diff.NextDifference` command with keyboard shortcut while in Text Editor
From the docs
Difference Viewer: context specific shortcuts
The shortcuts specific to this context are:
Next difference F8  Diff.NextDifference. Can I achieve this with a macro?

I want to use the Diff.NextDifference command in the Text Editor context.
I've added a global keyboard shortcut but it doesn't do anything unless the difference viewer is open.
Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the Diff Viewer to a head diff of the current buffer in the editor? Tools.DiffFiles again doesn't do anything.

If you want to know if there is a keyboard shortcut to open Difference Viewer, I did not find any information after searching. However, based on the existence of text files, you can refer to the following two methods I gave to open the Difference Viewer for comparison:
1: If the text file only exists in VS, you can refer to this method:
Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, find Diff.CompareSelected, enter the shortcut key you want to set in the Press shortcut keys below, and then click Assign:

Finally, find the two text files you want to compare in your VS, select them and use the shortcut keys you set.
2: We can open Difference Viewer through the command line in VS(Ctrl+Alt+A), such as using this command:
Tools.DiffFiles YourtextfilePath1 YourtextfilePath2


I wanted to open the difference viewer of a head diff of the current file in the editor. Diff.CompareSelected doesn't really do that. But thanks anyway. The idea is to jump around a long file without saving bookmarks

I don't quite understand what you mean, and I noticed that you edited the statement. Could you describe the effect you want in more detail, or can you add an image to show the effect you want?

If you go to Git Changes and double click on a file, it opens up a git diff of your changes. F8 will jump from change to change. When I am in the editor, I want to do that only from the keyboard, without having to use my mouse.

After some searching and testing, I did not find this feature. If you really want this feature, I recommend you request this feature from DC. There are more VS developers on DC, and they may be able to help you: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
